# Rate limit for ARP requests using nftables

Tags: arp

I am currently trying to limit the ARP traffic using nftables. I am using the folowing rules:

```
table arp filter {
        chain input {
                limit rate 15/second accept # handle 3
        }

        chain output {
        }
}
```

However, these show no effect. What I am doing wrong? I also tried dropping all packets not matching the first rule.

```
table arp filter {
        chain input {
                limit rate 10/second accept # handle 3
                drop # handle 4
        }

        chain output {
        }
}
```

**EDIT:** I have added the following lines to the chains:

```
type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
```

This leaves me with the following configuration:

```
table arp filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
                limit rate 10/second accept # handle 3
                drop # handle 4
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        }
}
```

This works fine, but why?

Comment: Please translate your update to English: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because in nftables chains are not automatically associated with a table, so we have to explicitly define a hook to activate a chain.   Note that each address family has a different set of hooks:  https://www.mankier.com/8/nft#Address_Families